# Rename file location AJAX PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am developing a sort of library in which a user is able to upload different files and then only post those desired.

When the user uploads a file or files, these will be stored in a temporary folder. Later, by filling a form the user can post a selected file. As soon as the user pushs the submit button I want to move the file from the temporary folder to another folder suggested by the user.

At the moment, I am able to create the suggested folder. Nevertheless, I am getting an "access denied (code 5)" error, and the files do not appear on the new folder. I've read other issues, and added "Read and Write" permissions to my all users for all folders inside htdocs(XAMPP folder). Still, the error continues to appear.

I am running this script in an AJAX file (shown below in the JS code).

Here is my code. Hope you can help me and this can help others! Than you

```js
// When the form is submitted we want for the temp file to be moved to the directory chosen by the user
  $( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
   $directory = $('#directory').val();
   $file = $('#fileid').val();
   $.ajax({

     url:'ajax/rename.php',
     type:"POST",
     data:({ directory:$directory,
       file:$file 
      }),
     success:function(data){
     //window.location.href = 'home';//redirect to the homepage
     alert(data);
    },
     error: function(xhr, status, error) {
       var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
       alert(err.Message);
     }
   });event.preventDefault();
  });

AJAX CODE

<?php

 require_once '../../app/models/DB.php';
 require_once '../../app/models/Files.php';
 require_once '../../app/init.php';
  $db= DB::getInstance();
  $files= new Files();
  $directory = $_POST['directory'];
  $file = $_POST['file'];
  if (!file_exists('../' . $directory)) {
   mkdir('../' . $directory, 0744, true);
   chmod('../'. $directory, 0777);
  }
  $currentdirectory = $db->query("SELECT path FROM file WHERE id = '$file'")->first()->path;
  rename('../' . $currentdirectory,'../' . $directory);
  $data = $db->query("UPDATE file SET path = '$directory' WHERE id = '$file'");
  

  echo('../' . $currentdirectory);
  ?>
```

```css
.secondaryContainer{
  margin:0 auto; width:86%;
  height:58px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,#FBFBFB,#A7A6A6) #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
 }
 #HomesearchBar{
  float:right;
 }

 .boxHeader{
  padding:15px 15px 0px 15px ;
 }

 #headerTab{
  border-bottom:0px;
 }
 .filesBoxContent{
  background-color: #aeaeae !important;
     border-color: #818181 !important;
     border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
 }

 #MainPageThumbnails{
  margin-top: 15px;
 }

 #MainPageThumbnails{
  text-align:justify;
 }


 .clicked {
    border: 3px solid blue;
}
  #mainPage{
   max-width: 900px;
  }
  #mainPage h1, #mainPage h2 {
      font-size: 28px;
      color: #25A7DE;
      font-weight: lighter;
      text-align: left;
  }
  .postPage legend {
      text-align: center;
      background: #25A7DE;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 18px;
      padding: 4px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 34px;
      -moz-border-radius: 34px;
      border-radius: 34px;
      width: 34px;
      height: 34px;
  }
  fieldset{
      border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  }

  .fileUpload {
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      margin: 10px;
  }
  .fileUpload input.upload {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-size: 20px;
      cursor: pointer;
      opacity: 0;
      filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  }

  #banner_warning{
   float:left;
  }

  .form-actions {
      margin: 0;
      background-color: transparent;
      text-align: center;
  }
  /*---------Category CSS-------*/
  .subcategoryList,.categoryList {
      border-radius: 15px;
      background-color: white;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      padding: 5px;
      min-height:150px;
      max-height:150px;
      overflow-y: auto;
      overflow-x:hidden;
      margin-bottom:20px !important;
  }
  .categoryList{
   float: left;
   width:49%;

  }
  .subcategoryList{
   float: right;
   width:49%;
   visibility: hidden;
  }
  .subcategoryList ul,.categoryList ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .subcategory,.category {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    -webkit-transition: font-size 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: font-size 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: font-size 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: font-size 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
    transition: font-size 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
    display: block;
  }
  .subcategory:hover,.category:hover {
    font-size: 15px;
    background: #f6f6f6;
  }

  .input-group{
   z-index: 0;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Form Container -->
<div id="mainPage" class="container">
 <h1>Add New Post</h1>
 <div class = "postPage">
  <form action="" method="post">
     <fieldset class="form-group">
      <legend>1</legend>
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Title*</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="title" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" placeholder="Enter the post title">
    </div>

    <div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary">
        <span>Choose Banner</span>
        <input type="file" name="banner" id="uploadBtn" class="upload" />
    </div>
    <span id="thumbnail" ></span>
    <div id="banner_warning">
     <small class="banner">Choose a banner for your post.</small>
       </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Description*</span>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="description" id="description" rows="10" placeholder="Type a short description for this file"></textarea>
       </div>
     </fieldset>

     <fieldset class="form-group">
      <legend>2</legend>
      <div class="categoryList">
      <ul>
       <?php foreach($category as $item):?>
         <li class="category" id="<?php echo $item->id;?>"><?php echo $item->name; ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </ul>
      <input type="hidden" name="category" id="category"/>
    </div>
    <div class="subcategoryList">
      <ul>
      </ul>
      <input type="hidden" name="subcategory" id="subcategory"/>
    </div>
           
      <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
      <div class="form-actions">
       <button type="button" id="myBtn" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip" aria-hidden="true"></span> Add Media
     </button>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Directory</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="directory" id="directory" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
        <input type="hidden" name="filename" id="filename"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="fileid" id="fileid"/>
    </div>
   </fieldset>

   <fieldset class="form-group">
      <legend>3</legend>
      <label for="keywords"><h3>Keywords</h3></label>
       <textarea class="form-control" name="keywords" id="keywords" rows="3"></textarea>
       <small class="text-muted">Separate words by either '/' or ';'</small>
     </fieldset>
     
    
   <!--Token will be generated here. Model Token will be called for this-->
   <input type="hidden" name = "token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
   <input type="submit" value="Post"> 
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
<!-- End of Form Container -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly i would suggest your sanitize the user input:

```
$directory = $_POST['directory'];
$file = $_POST['file'];
```

Later you use $directory in SQL query, could give SQL injection issue.

Secondly check all the file/folder permissions of the parent folder in which the mkdir command makes its new folder.